# Measurability of $f+g$ if $f+g$ is in the form of $\infty - \infty$ or $-\infty + \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f,g$ be measurable, extended real valued functions. ($f:\Bbb{R} \to \bar{\Bbb{R}}, \ g:\Bbb{R} \to \bar{\Bbb{R}}, \ \bar{\Bbb{R}}=\Bbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty \})  $. Prove if $\alpha$ is an arbitrary number then function $f+g$ is measurable if we assume  that $f+g$ is equal $\alpha$ in every point of domain, where $f+g$ is in the form of $\infty - \infty$ or $-\infty + \infty$.

1.What does it mean that function $f+g$ has form $\infty - \infty$ or $-\infty + \infty$?

2.I know  that extended real valued function $f$ is measurable if its domain is measurable  and set $\forall \alpha \in \Bbb{R} \{x: f(x) < \alpha \}$ is measurable.

3.Maybe I should consider the restriction of function and sets $D_{+\infty}=\{x: f(x) = +\infty \}$ and $D_{-\infty}=\{x: f(x) = -\infty \}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your definition correctly, then we have to choose some $\alpha\in \bar{\mathbb R}$, then define $f+g$ pointwise
$$
(f+g)(x) = \begin{cases} f(x)+g(x) & \text{ if } f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb R,\\
\pm\infty & \text{ if } f(x)=\pm \infty,g(x)\in\mathbb R\\
\pm\infty & \text{ if } f(x)\in\mathbb R,g(x)=\pm \infty\\
\alpha & \text{ if } f(x)=+\infty, g(x)=-\infty\\
\alpha & \text{ if } f(x)=-\infty, g(x)=+\infty.
\end{cases}
$$
So we set $(f+g)(x)$ to be $\alpha$ for all $x$ for which $f(x)+g(x)$ is not defined on $\bar{\mathbb R}$. Which is the case if one of these is $+\infty$ and the other $-\infty$.

The resulting function $f+g$ again a measurable function.

Comment: Ok, now I see how function looks but I don't know how to explain that it is measurable in the last two cases.

Comment: You can write  $f+g = \chi_A (f+g) + \chi_{\mathbb R\setminus A} \alpha$ with a suitable subset $A\subset \mathbb R$.